# R - Replace missing values with another value of the same entry

Tags: r

I have a table "Passengers" with the columns "ID", "Name", "Fare" and "TravelClass". 
The "Fare" vector has missing values. For each entry, I want to replace the missing value in "Fare" with a multiplied value of its "TravelClass" value.

In PseudoCode:

```
For each i in Passengers{
 if(is.na(i.Fare)){
  i.Fare = i.Class*10
 }
}
```

Any help welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `within` could be a handy way to avoid repeated references to the `Passengers` data.frame, i.e.:

```
Passengers <- within(Passengers,Fare[is.na(Fare)] <- TravelClass[is.na(Fare)]*10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Passengers$Fare[is.na(Passengers$Fare)] <- Passengers$Class[is.na(Passengers$Fare)]*10
```